# Bootstrap popover behaviour after cloning

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap-3, popover

I have a list looking like this:

```
<ul> 
  <li class="list">...</li>
  <li class="list">...</li>
  <li class="root">
    <ul>
      <li class="list">...</li>
      <li class="list">...</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  ...
</ul>
```

I have filter functionality that takes all list elements (with class list). 
Those elements have  tag with popover, which works before filtering elements.

Filtering takes all list elements, deep clones them, filters them by name and hides original list while appending new list (works as expected). 
All functionalities of those elements work, but popover fails (event gets triggered, but it adds/tries to add popover to the original list element - it shoes up on top left corner since that one is hidden or in case I remove it, it doesn't get showed.

Is there something I'm missing, or what's going wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Popover is a js functionality and it is assinged to an element. If you clone an element the popover is still assigned to the same element.

You should trigger popover in js after creating cloned elements. And it would be a good idea to remove old elements, or at least delete popover tags.

Every time you change elements you should trigger popover in js. So it can assign to proper element.

I hope that helps

Cheers

Comment: Thank you! It solved my problem. I removed old img element and added new one with new popover.